# Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views

Tags: java, android, tabs, fragment

> i do like this 
>   http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/
>
> what should i add code each tab?
>
> i have a function in MainActivity
>
> test() {    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFrag1);
>   tv1.setText("test"); }
>
> just example .. and i call test() in onCreate ... ERROR
>
> i try alert that error "java.lang.NullPointerException"
>
> but, call test() in viewPageChangeListener no error ( swipetab 1st )
>   i wanna setText when open activity before swipetab
>
> help me pleaseeee
>
> ps. sorry for my english